# Sequential input in C

Tags: c, parsing, input

Let's say I am creating a 3*4 matrix (or a 2D array of 12 elements). So I want user to enter values of elements one by one as a sequence, divided by **either** *spaces/tabs* or *enter-key*. Also, if a value in a sequence is bad (in my case, any non-integer values are bad), I want to ignore it and read next values until I have all 12 of them.

```
int fill(Matrix * mtx)
{
    puts("Start entering numbers. Please note that only integer values will be recorded.");

    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= mtx -> rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= mtx -> cols; j++)
        {
            scanf(" %d", &temp);

            setElement(mtx, i, j, temp);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my most basic vision of the algorithm; I was wondering about the implementation of this "skip input if bad" condition.

Just started learning C btw, so any kind of advice is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Read the input into strings. Use `strtol()` to convert it to a number, and its return value can be used to detect if it's valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the return value of `scanf` to be sure whether it scanned the integer input correctly or not. In case it fails due to some bad input - `scanf` can't take that as input and then you have to make sure that you clear the `stdin` so that the next calls of `scanf` don't fail. What you can do is, when `scanf` returns `0` - consume all characters (using `getchar` or similar) and do this until you get `\n` (Considering that user inputs the number each in a line). Illustration would be:

```
int n; //total number inputs to take.
n = 10;
int num, num_inputs = 0; 
while( 1 )
{
   while(scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
   {
       int c;
       while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
          ;
       if(c == EOF){ fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n"); exit(1)} 
   }
   num_inputs++; // one more int correctly input.
   ...
   if( num_inputs == n )
      break;
}
```

An alternative and better way would be to use `strto*` functions and then considering the return value of it to understand whether there is any error or not. Illustration would be: (Here we have shown just the case where there is single `int` input in each line - this can be extended to process multiple `int` inputs in a line).

```
char buf[MAXLEN];
int num_inputs = 0;
while(fgets(buf,MAXLEN,stdin)){
    char *en;
    errno = 0;
    long n = strtol(line, &en, 10);
    if (errno == 0 && *en== '\0' && n >= INT_MIN && n < INT_MAX)
    {
        // n is an correctly inputted int
        num_inputs++;
    }
}
```

Check the man page for `strtol` - there is a detailed listing of the erros one might get. Check it.

Answer (score 3):

Check what `scanf` returns. If not `1` means entered value is not a digit in this case. So discard the data from the stream first before entering next data.

```
int fill(Matrix * mtx) {
    puts("Start entering numbers. Please note that only integer values will be recorded."); 
    int temp = 0, v; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= mtx->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= mtx->cols; j++) {
            v = scanf(" %d", &temp); 
            if (v != 1) {  //if invalid input.
                while ( (v = getchar()) != EOF && v != '\n' );  // discard invalid input.
                j--;  //don't forget to `j--` or else you will skip one position.
            }
            else {  // if correct input.
                setElement(mtx, i, j, temp); 
            }
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should never have spaces around them.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that one. Thank you for pointing that out. :)  See edited.